# How to set a UISlider using a delegate method from UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift

I'm setting up a `MainViewController` and a `PopUpViewController`.

In the `MainVC` I have a slider which represent the height from **0 to 800** cm. Also here I have 2 labels which represent the conversion of that centimeters in **Feets+Inches** and **Meters+Centimeters**.

In `HeightTableViewCell`, I have all the outlets and the slider and there I have a delegate to communicate with the `MainVC`.

In `PopUpViewController`, I have a save button and 3 `UITextFields` (Centimeters, Feet and Inches). When I press the save button I want to set in the `MainVC` the slider with the right value and to display in the labels the conversion.

How do I need to set the `UISlider` using that delegates methods because I can't access the `UISlider` this being in the `TableViewCell` ?

I already tried to pass the data with the delegates. Is there any other better way to do it ?

Here is my MainVC:

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController {

    var sliderValue: Float = 0.0    

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}

extension MainViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "heightCell", for: indexPath) as! HeightTableViewCell
        cell.configVehicleHeightCell(sliderValue)
        cell.delegate = self

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0: return 150
        default:
            return 150
        }
    }
}

// Receive data from the Cell to MainVC
extension MainViewController: HeightCellDelegate {

    func heightSliderValueChanged(_ slider: UISlider, _ feetsLabel: UILabel, _ metersLabel: UILabel) {

        let currentValue = Int(slider.value)
        let meters = currentValue / 100
        let centimeters = currentValue % 100
        let inches = currentValue < 3 ? 0 : round(Double(currentValue) / 2.54)
        let feet = round(inches / 12)
        let inch = round(inches.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 12))

        feetsLabel.text = "\(feet) ft" + " \(inch)\""
        metersLabel.text = "\(meters) m" + " \(centimeters) cm"
    }
}

// Receive data (centimeters) from the PopUp to MainVC
extension MainViewController: HeightPopUpDelegate {

    func receiveHeightMetric(centimeters: Float?) {
        print("\n\nMetric Data received")
        print("Centimeters: \(centimeters ?? 0)")

        sliderValue = Float(centimeters ?? 0)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func receiveHeightImperial(feet: Int?, inches: Int?) {

        print("\n\nImperial Data received")
        print("Feet: \(feet ?? 0)")
        print("Inches: \(inches ?? 0)")
    }

    // Receive the data from PopUpViewController
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        if segue.identifier == "goToHeight" {
            let vc: PopUpViewController = segue.destination as! PopUpViewController
            vc.delegate = self
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my Cell for MainVC:

```
protocol HeightCellDelegate {
    func heightSliderValueChanged(_ slider: UISlider, _ feetsLabel: UILabel, _ metersLabel: UILabel)
}

class HeightTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    // Interface Links
    @IBOutlet weak var heightLabelTitle: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var heightSlider: UISlider!
    @IBOutlet weak var heightFeetsLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var heightMetersLabel: UILabel!

    // Properties
    var delegate: HeightCellDelegate?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }

   func configVehicleHeightCell(_ value : Float){

    heightSlider.value = value
    heightLabelTitle.text = "Height"


    let meters  = Int((value) / 100)
    let centimeters  = Int(value.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 100))
    let inches = Int(value) < 3 ? 0 : round((value) / 2.54)
    let feet = Int(round(inches / 12))
    let inch = Int(round(inches.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 12)))

    heightFeetsLabel.text = "\(feet) ft" + " \(inch)\""
    heightMetersLabel.text = "\((meters)) m" + " \((centimeters)) cm"
}

    @IBAction func heightValueChanged(_ sender: UISlider) {

        configVehicleHeightCell(sender.value)
    }
}
```

Here is my code for the PopUpVC:

```
protocol HeightPopUpDelegate {
    func receiveHeightMetric(centimeters: Int?)
    func receiveHeightImperial(feet: Int?, inches: Int?)
}

class PopUpViewController: UIViewController {

    // Interface Links
    @IBOutlet weak var centimetersTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var feetTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var inchesTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelForOr: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var popUpView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var cancelBtnOutlet: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var saveBtnOutlet: UIButton!

    // Properties
    var delegate: HeightPopUpDelegate?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupViews()
    }

    // Dismiss the popup when user press the Cancel btn
    @IBAction func cancelBtnTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    // Save the data and send it back when user press the Save btn
    @IBAction func saveBtnTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

        checkImperialOrMetricTextfields()
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    // Check if the textfields contains Metric or Imperial height. If everything is OK then send the data back.
    func checkImperialOrMetricTextfields(){

        if ((!(centimetersTextField.text?.isEmpty)!) && (!(feetTextField.text?.isEmpty)! || !(inchesTextField.text?.isEmpty)!)) {

            showAlertWithTitle(title: "Error", message: "Enter either metric OR imperial height.")
            clearTextFields()
        }
        if ((centimetersTextField.text?.isEmpty)! && (feetTextField.text?.isEmpty)! && (inchesTextField.text?.isEmpty)!) {

            showAlertWithTitle(title: "Error", message: "Enter either metric OR imperial height.")
            clearTextFields()
        }
        else{
            sendDataBack()
        }
    }

    // Clear textfields
    func clearTextFields(){

        centimetersTextField.text = ""
        feetTextField.text = ""
        inchesTextField.text = ""
    }

    // Function used to send data back from the PopUp to MainVC
    func sendDataBack(){

        if delegate != nil{
            delegate?.receiveHeightMetric(centimeters: Int(centimetersTextField?.text ?? "0"))
            delegate?.receiveHeightImperial(feet: Int(feetTextField?.text ?? "0"), inches: Int(inchesTextField?.text ?? "0"))
        }
    }

    // Setup the design for outlets
    func setupViews(){

        popUpView.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        popUpView.layer.masksToBounds = true

        cancelBtnOutlet.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        cancelBtnOutlet.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
        cancelBtnOutlet.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor

        saveBtnOutlet.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        saveBtnOutlet.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
        saveBtnOutlet.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    }

    // Function to hide the Popup when the user click anywhere on the screen
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let touch = touches.first
        if touch?.view == self.view {
            dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    // Show an alert view with Title
    func showAlertWithTitle(title: String = "", message: String) {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
        alertController.addAction(OKAction)
        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

For the moment when I set something in PopUp and I click 'Save' I get in the console the value from that textfields:

```
Metric Data received
Centimeters: 0

Imperial Data received
Feet: 23
Inches: 45
```

Here is a link for this small example if is helping anyone:
https://github.com/tygruletz/ImperialAndMetricMeasurement

Thank you so much if you read this and I hope I provide the right details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have made some changes and below is the working example for `cm/m`,

1. In `HeightTableViewCell`, set your label and slider here. few places i set Int to Float.

   ```
   func configVehicleHeightCell(_ value : Float){
       heightSlider.value = value
       heightLabelTitle.text = "Height"


       let meters  = Int((value) / 100)
       let centimeters  = Int(value.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 100))
       let inches = Int(value) < 3 ? 0 : round((value) / 2.54)
       let feet = Int(round(inches / 12))
       let inch = Int(round(inches.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 12)))

       heightFeetsLabel.text = "\(feet) ft" + " \(inch)\""
       heightMetersLabel.text = "\((meters)) m" + " \((centimeters)) cm"
   }
   ```
2. You do not need delegate any more, on `heightValueChanged`

   ```
   @IBAction func heightValueChanged(_ sender: UISlider) {

       configVehicleHeightCell((sender.value))
   }
   ```
3. In `MainVC`, create `var sliderValue : Float  = 0.0`
4. In cellForRow, `cell.configVehicleHeightCell(sliderValue)`
5. And now finally, when user input data in alert (in cm textfield working)

   ```
   func receiveHeightMetric(centimeters: Float?) {
       print("\n\nMetric Data received")
       print("Centimeters: \(centimeters ?? 0)")

       sliderValue = centimeters ?? 0
       mtTableView.reloadData()
   }
   ```

**Output:**

[image]

> Edit

For `feet/inch`, just do below only

```
func receiveHeightImperial(feet: Int?, inches: Int?){
   // 1. convert feet, inch into centimeter.    
   // 2. If either of feet/inch is nil then consider it as zero, for safety
   // 3. Now, sliderValue = new_cm_value (value that you calculated from feet/inch)
   // 4. Now reloadData().
}
```

Comment: Works fantastic ! I just added an outlet for my tableView to be able to reload the view and that's it ! Thank you so so much for your help ! I can't give you rep because I have only few coins but I will do it later on !

Comment: is there any way to make the Feet and Inches to also work without to change too much the functionality ?

Comment: @Flo I didnt know what part you took from answer that make your code work. Please edit your post and let me know. Btw its not too much changes but for beginner it might looked like.. mostly I shifted your code in proper way so that it will work with less efforts... check again the answer..best practice always save you in bad time.

Answer (score 0):

You have only one cell, so you can:

`MainVC`

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    func receiveHeightMetric(centimeters: Int?) {
        print("\n\nMetric Data received")
        print("Centimeters: \(centimeters ?? 0)")

        let cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)) as! HeightTableViewCell
        cell.refresh(centimeters: centimeters)
    }

    func receiveHeightImperial(feet: Int?, inches: Int?) {

        print("\n\nImperial Data received")
        print("Feet: \(feet ?? 0)")
        print("Inches: \(inches ?? 0)")


        let cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)) as! HeightTableViewCell
        cell.refresh(feet: feet, inches: inches)
    }
```

`HeightTableViewCell`

```
    func refresh(centimeters: Int?) {
        print("\n\nMetric Data received in cell")
        print("Centimeters: \(centimeters ?? 0)")
    }
    func refresh(feet: Int?, inches: Int?) {

        print("\n\nImperial Data received in cell")
        print("Feet: \(feet ?? 0)")
        print("Inches: \(inches ?? 0)")
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a protocol for the `UIViewController`, which will be conformed by the `UITableViewCell`.

say-

```
protocol UpdateSlider : class {

    func updateSlider(with value : CGFloat)

}
```

now your MainViewController will have a variable of this protocol and you will assign a value to this variable in `cellForRowAt` method by the reference of the cell.

```
class MainViewController : UIViewController {

    weak var delegate : UpdateSlider?
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "heightCell", for: indexPath) as! HeightTableViewCell
    cell.configVehicleHeightCell()
    cell.delegate = self
    self.delegate = cell
    return cell
}
```

whenever you want to update the value of your slider, just call the delegate method of your `MainViewController`.

```
self.delegate?.updateSlider(with value : <#CustomValue#>)
```

P.S. - You can always set the current values in the `cellForRowAt` and reload cell whenever you need to.