# How do I set calculations in labels using a delegate method from UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, tableview

I'm setting up a CartViewController and a PopUpFeesController.

In the CartVC I have a cells that add up inside the CartFooter cartTotal label which represent the subtotal. Also here I have 3 labels which represent the conversion of subtotal, salesTax, and total in the PopUpFeesController.

In the CartFooter, I have all the outlets and have a delegate to communicate with the CartVC.
popupFeesBtn

In PopupFeesController, I have  3 UILabels (sTotal, stax and oaTotal). When I press the popupFeesBtn(in the CartFooter) I want to set in the PopupFeesController the labels with the right value to display the conversion in the labels.

How do I need to set the UILabel(cartTotal) using that delegates methods because I can't convert  the cartTotal to the labels in the PopupFeesController?

how would I be able to get the the subtotal passed from the CartVC CartFooter Cell cartFooter label to the PopUpFeesViewController so that that it can calculate the the tax and overaltotal from the subtotal and present them in the labels of the PopUpFeesViewController

ive tried to set up my code similar to the code in the link below

[How to set a UISlider using a delegate method from UITableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55377504/how-to-set-a-uislider-using-a-delegate-method-from-uitableviewcell)

I already tried to pass the data with the delegates. Is there any other better way to do it ?

---

```
import UIKit

class CartViewController: UIViewController {

    var selectedFood: FoodList!       // allows data to be passed into the CartVC

    var cartValue : Float  = 0.0

    // allows data to be sepearted into sections
    var cartItems: [CartItem] = []
    var groupedCartItems: [String: [CartItem]] = [:]
    var storeSectionTitle: [String] = []

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "AdditionalCosts" {
        let vc: PopupFeesController = segue.destination as! PopupFeesController
            vc.calculateFeesDelegate = self
        }
    }
}
extension CartViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return storeSectionTitle.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        let store = storeSectionTitle[section]
    return groupedCartItems[store]!.count
}

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cartCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CartCell") as! CartCell

        let store = storeSectionTitle[indexPath.section]
        let cartItemsToDisplay = groupedCartItems[store]![indexPath.row]
        cartCell.configure(withCartItems: cartItemsToDisplay.foodList)

        return cartCell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let cartHeader = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CartHeader") as! CartHeader

        let headerTitle = storeSectionTitle[section]
        cartHeader.storeName.text = "\(headerTitle)"

        return cartHeader
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let cartFooter = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CartFooter") as! CartFooter

        //Cell Total Code
        let store = storeSectionTitle[section]
        let arrAllItems = groupedCartItems[store]!
        var subtotal: Float = 0
        for item in arrAllItems {
            if item.productList.selectedOption == 1 {
                subtotal = subtotal + (Float(item.foodList.price) * Float(item.foodList.count))
            }
        }

        let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
        numberFormatter.numberStyle = .currency
        let total = numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: Float(subtotal)))
        subtotal = cartValue

        cartFooter.cartTotal.text = String(total!)
        cartFooter.additionalCostsDelegate = self

        return cartFooter
    }    
}

extension CartViewController: AdditionalCostsDelegate {
    func onTouchAdditionalCostsInfo(info: Float?) {
        let popUp = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AdditionalCostsVC") as! PopUpViewController
        print("Subtotal: \(cartValue)")
        cartValue = Float(info ?? 0.00)

        self.present(popUp, animated: true) {
            popUp.subtotalLbl.text = "\(String(describing: info))"
        }
    }
}

extension CartViewController: CalculateFeesDelegate {
    func calculateFees(_ stotal: UILabel, _ sTax: UILabel, _ oaTotal: UILabel) {

        let subtotal = cartValue
        let tax = subtotal * Float(0.0825)
        let total = subtotal + tax

        let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
        numberFormatter.numberStyle = .currency
        let total = numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: Float(subtotal)))
        let salesTax = numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: Float(tax)))
        let overallTotal = numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: Float(total)))

        stotal.text = "\(String(describing: total))"
        sTax.text = "\(String(describing: marijuanaTax))"
        oaTotal.text = "\(String(describing: overallTotal))"
    }    
}
```

---

```
protocol AdditionalCostsDelegate: class {
    func onTouchAdditionalCostsInfo(info: Float?)
}

class CartFooter: UITableViewCell {

    var additionalCostsDelegate: AdditionalCostsDelegate? = nil

    @IBOutlet weak var cartTotal: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var popupFeesBtn: UIButton!

    @IBAction func popFeesOnClicked(_ sender: Any) {
        sendData2PopupFees()
    }

    func sendData2PopupFees(){
        self.additionalCostsDelegate?.onTouchAdditionalCostsInfo(info: Float(cartTotal?.text! ?? "0.0"))
    }
}
```

---

```
protocol CalculateFeesDelegate {
    func calculateFees(_ stotal: UILabel, _ sTax: UILabel, _ oaTotal: UILabel)
}

class PopupFeesController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var subtotalLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var salesTaxLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var overallTotalLbl: UILabel!

    var calculateFeesDelegate: CalculateFeesDelegate?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let subtotal = Float(subtotalLbl.text!)

        let tax = Float((subtotal) * 0.0825) // getting an error here when pressing popupFeesBtn => Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
        let total = Float((subtotal) + salesTax)
        let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
        numberFormatter.numberStyle = .currency
        let sTotal = numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: Float(subtotal!)))
        let salesTax = numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: Float(tax)))
        let overallTotal = numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: Float(total)))

        subtotalLbl.text = "\(subTotal)"
        salesTaxLbl.text = "\(salesTax)"
        overallTotalLbl.text = "\(total)"
    }

    @IBAction func returnButton(_ sender: Any) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}

class CartItem {
    var foodList: FoodList!

    init(foodList: FoodList) {

        foodList = foodList
    }
}
```

Comment: A general advice, don't do everything in your view controllers. Try to move business logic (like calculations) to separate model classes/or structs. For instance you could perhaps let `CartItem` do some of the calculations and introduce a struct `Cart` that holds the array of `CartItem` and can perform various calculations on them.

Comment: ***@JoakimDanielson***, I just added the code to my CartItem class. Could you show me an example of how I could do that? Because im not so sure how would go about that route. since all im trying to do is pull the subtotal from the CartFooter viewForFooterInSection to the PopupFeesVC. how would I be able to integrate that into a struct/class ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all I would like to tell you have done everything according to your requirements. You have to just create a variable which would be of Float type in class **PopupFeesController**. You have to pass the value from this method "onTouchAdditionalCostsInfo" to PopupFeesController.

You have to replace the **PopupFeesController** code and the "**onTouchAdditionalCostsInfo**" with your code and your data would be passed from one View controller to another view controller.

```
class PopupFeesController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var subtotalLbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var salesTaxLbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var overallTotalLbl: UILabel!

var calculateFeesDelegate: CalculateFeesDelegate?
var totalCartValue : Float  = 0.0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    print("\(totalCartValue)")
    let subtotal = Float(subtotalLbl.text!)

    let tax = Float((subtotal) * 0.0825) // getting an error here when pressing popupFeesBtn => Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
    let total = Float((subtotal) + salesTax)
    let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
    numberFormatter.numberStyle = .currency
    let sTotal = numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: Float(subtotal!)))
    let salesTax = numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: Float(tax)))
    let overallTotal = numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: Float(total)))

    subtotalLbl.text = "\(subTotal)"
    salesTaxLbl.text = "\(salesTax)"
    overallTotalLbl.text = "\(total)"
}

@IBAction func returnButton(_ sender: Any) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

}


extension CartViewController: AdditionalCostsDelegate {
  func onTouchAdditionalCostsInfo(info: Float?) {
    let popUp = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AdditionalCostsVC") as! PopUpViewController
    popUp.totalCartValue = Float(info ?? 0.00)
    self.present(popUp, animated: true) {
        popUp.subtotalLbl.text = "\(String(describing: info))"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for that's the first time someone said something nice about my code :). The answer you gave me seems to be working at getting data to pass, but the PopupFeesController is showing ***"nil"*** in the ```subtotalLbl``` and ***"Optional("0.00")"*** in the ```salesTaxLbl``` & ```overallTotalLbl```

Comment: @Evelyn, you have to check in this method "onTouchAdditionalCostsInfo". The value you are getting in this method, try to print the value of "info" variable. And then check whether you are getting the value or nil value in this variable.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add as subView your UILabel into UItableviewcell container view.
2. Add Trailing, Leading, Top, Bottom constrains.
3. Set UILabel number of lines 0.
4. Add override heightForRowAt method for dynamic height.

   ```
   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt 
   indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
   }
   ```

Comment: this is not relevant to the question, but thank you for the help